# Using two session modes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have a web application which uses the In-Proc session mode.A new "**Quiz**" section needs to be introduced in the website. This "**Quiz**" has its own sets of business rules that is to be followed (negative marking, mark for review etc) since the data is also important here (who answered what) so I decided to go for the SQL Server Out-Proc session mode for only the mock test functionality. Is it actually possible to have two session modes (In-Proc and out-Proc, both in one web application)?.

If yes, then how do i explicitly mention to use Out-proc mode for the pages under the **/mocktest** folders and In-Proc for the rest of the website in the web config ?

I am posting this question after a lot of searching through google with no pointers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it actually possible to do so? i mean, having two session modes
>   (In-Proc and out-Proc, both in one web application)

You can achieve this but not by having 2 session modes at a time, but by implemeting your own custom session state store provider.
But in your custom implementation you need to store your session data in SQL storage as well as memory at the same time. and provide a specific retrieval mechanism.

try :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178588%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

> If yes, then how do i explicitly mention to use Out-proc mode for the
>   pages under the /mocktest folders and In-Proc for the rest of the
>   website in the web config ?

I do not think it is possible, though others may have more information about the topic more than i do.

My suggestion:

Keep using the In-Proc session-state mode, but make your own specific DataAccessLayer for the "Quiz" section and use it to store/retrieve what you need on SQL Server